# jquery 4 sections animation on click

Tags: jquery, html, animation, click, toggle

I want a webpage that is split up in 4 vertical sections.
They are all 25% in width and 100vh in height.
If you click on one section that section needs to be 70% and the other 3 10%
my code now is:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#profile" ).click(function() {
        $( this ).toggleClass( 'bigsection' );
        $( "#info" ).toggleClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( "#cv" ).toggleClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( "#portfolio" ).toggleClass( 'smallsection' );

    });
    $( "#info" ).click(function() {
        $( this ).toggleClass( 'bigsection' );
        $( "#profile" ).toggleClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( "#cv" ).toggleClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( "#portfolio" ).toggleClass( 'smallsection' );
    });
    $( "#cv" ).click(function() {
        $( this ).toggleClass( 'bigsection' );
        $( "#info" ).toggleClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( "#profile" ).toggleClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( "#portfolio" ).toggleClass( 'smallsection' );
    });
    $( "#portfolio" ).click(function() {
        $( this ).toggleClass( 'bigsection' );
        $( "#info" ).toggleClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( "#cv" ).toggleClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( "#profile" ).toggleClass( 'smallsection' );
    }); 
});
```

It works as long as you click one div and than click the same div to close it first and then open another.
but if you click one div and then click another div it won't work properly.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered my own question with this:

```
var $a = 0;
$( "#info" ).click(function() {
    if ($a == 0) {
        $( "#info" ).addClass( 'bigsection' );
        $( "#cv" ).addClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( "#portfolio" ).addClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( ".buttoninfo" ).html("Close");
        $a = 2;
    }
    else if ($a == 2) {
        $( "#info" ).removeClass( 'bigsection' );
        $( "#cv" ).removeClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( "#portfolio" ).removeClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( ".buttoninfo" ).html("Open");
        $a = 0;
    }
    else if ($a == 3 || $a == 4) {
        $( "#info" ).addClass( 'bigsection' );
        $( "#info" ).removeClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( "#cv" ).removeClass( 'bigsection' );
        $( "#cv" ).addClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( ".cvsection" ).removeClass( 'block' );
        $( ".cvsection" ).addClass( 'none' );
        $( "#portfolio" ).removeClass( 'bigsection' );
        $( "#portfolio" ).addClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( ".buttoncv" ).html("Open");
        $( ".buttonportfolio" ).html("Open");
        $( ".buttoninfo" ).html("Open");
        $a = 2;
    }
});
$( "#cv" ).click(function() {
    if ($a == 0) {
        $( "#info" ).addClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( "#cv" ).addClass( 'bigsection' );
        $( "#portfolio" ).addClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( ".cvsection" ).removeClass( 'none' );
        $( ".cvsection" ).addClass( 'block' );
        $( ".buttoncv" ).html("Close");

        $a = 3;
    }
    else if ($a == 3) {
        $( "#info" ).removeClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( "#cv" ).removeClass( 'bigsection' );
        $( "#portfolio" ).removeClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( ".cvsection" ).removeClass( 'block' );
        $( ".cvsection" ).addClass( 'none' );
        $( ".buttoncv" ).html("Open");
        $a = 0;
    }
    else if ($a == 2 || $a == 4) {
        $( "#info" ).removeClass( 'bigsection' );
        $( "#info" ).addClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( "#cv" ).addClass( 'bigsection' );
        $( "#cv" ).removeClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( ".cvsection" ).removeClass( 'none' );
        $( ".cvsection" ).addClass( 'block' );
        $( "#portfolio" ).removeClass( 'bigsection' );
        $( "#portfolio" ).addClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( ".buttoninfo" ).html("Open");
        $( ".buttonportfolio" ).html("Open");
        $( ".buttoncv" ).html("Close");
        $a = 3;
    }

});
$( "#portfolio" ).click(function() {
    if ($a == 0) {
        $( "#info" ).addClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( "#cv" ).addClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( "#portfolio" ).addClass( 'bigsection' );
        $( ".buttonportfolio" ).html("Close");
        $a = 4;
    }
    else if ($a == 4) {
        $( "#info" ).removeClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( "#cv" ).removeClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( "#portfolio" ).removeClass( 'bigsection' );
        $( ".buttonportfolio" ).html("Open");
        $a = 0;
    }
    else if ($a == 2 || $a == 3) {
        $( "#info" ).removeClass( 'bigsection' );
        $( "#info" ).addClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( "#cv" ).removeClass( 'bigsection' );
        $( "#cv" ).addClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( ".cvsection" ).removeClass( 'block' );
        $( ".cvsection" ).addClass( 'none' );
        $( "#portfolio" ).addClass( 'bigsection' );
        $( "#portfolio" ).removeClass( 'smallsection' );
        $( ".buttoncv" ).html("Open");
        $( ".buttoninfo" ).html("Open");
        $( ".buttonportfolio" ).html("Close");
        $a = 4;
    }
});
```

I only think there will be a simpler solution to this.